# Linear equations in field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, extension-field

Let $F\subset E$ be a finite field extension of degree $2$ and $\,$ $^{-}:E\rightarrow E$ the conjugacy map. Consider the equation of the form
$$
ax+b\overline{x}=c, \qquad a,b,c\in E.
$$
Under what condition does this equation have a solution in $E$, and when is it unique?

Comment: "The" conjugacy map? First of all, there might not even be a conjugacy map. And even when there is one, there can easily be several. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Added: of degree 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a degree $2$ extension, everything looks like $u + vj$ for some chosen $j \in E$.  So, write $a = a_1 + a_2j$, $x = x_1 + x_2j$, and so on.  Rewrite $ax + b\bar{x} = c$ in terms of that, with $\bar{x} = x_1 - x_2j$.  Expand all that stuff out and match coefficients.  You end up with a matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 + b_1 & (a_2 - b_2)j^2 \\ a_2 + b_2 & a_1 - b_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
There is a unique solution when the determinant is nonzero.  That's when $a\bar{a} \neq b\bar{b}$.